# How to include the arrow head in the length of a line in SVG?

Tags: svg, line

In SVG one can define markers and use them as arrow heads. Is there a way to (automatically) include those markers in the length of a line?

Here is an example:

```
<svg width="600px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>

  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
  <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="250" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmZLRM

Here the arrow head gets attached to the end of the line which makes the line **including the arrow** head longer than the line on its own. I would like to have the line including the arrow head to have the same length as the line without it.

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `refX` attribute (I'm turning the line red, so you can better see where the marker ends):

```html
<svg width="600px" height="200px">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="8.7" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="250" y2="50" stroke="red" stroke-width="5" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
  <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="250" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I see the red line extending beyond the arrow head. That is not ideal. Is there no way to get around it?

Comment: Of course there is a way to get around it, simply change the `refX` value the way you want, which is the whole point of my answer. By the way, the line is not extending beyond the arrow, I made the line red exactly to show you this: as the arrow has a triangular form, if the very tip of the arrow ends at the same position of the line (which is what you asked in your question), you have to see a portion of the line (unless the line's width is infinitesimally small). Zoom in in your browser and you're gonna see that, with the value I'm using (8.7), the line actually ends **before** the arrow.

Comment: Thanks. But that you can see the line at the top of the arrow is what I meant with "extending beyond" it - I was a bit unclear. So, what I want is a line with an arrow head that starts and ends where the lower line does and without parts of the line extruding at the arrow head. Basically what one could expect if one drew an arrow from one point to another. And I don't want to manually fiddle with the length of the line.

Comment: I know what you want. But you have two problems: if the line and the line+arrow have exactly the same length, you'll see the line under the arrow. Second problem: you cannot get an "automatic" value, since the arrow size is defined by the `d` attribute, unless you write a JS to get the length of the arrow.

Comment: Well, I know the length of the arrow as defined in the marker definition. So the only thing that would be needed is an SVG attribute on the line to tell it to start/stop that amount after/before the start/end point. (This would then be scaled and rotated in the same way as the marker already automatically is.) So that would not require any fancy calculation not already done by the SVG marker feature. But unfortunately, there seems to be no such attribute. At least I could not find one.

Comment: I just found exactly the feature I was looking for: https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-markers/#MarkerKnockout. Unfortunately, it seems currently unsupported.

Comment: I realize more and more current downsides of using markers: it is not possible to use the stroke or fill color from the line and the bounding box does not include the marker. Looking forward to SVG 2.0 (which will support `context-stroke`, `context-fill`, `marker-knockout-left`, `marker-knockout-right` attributes. But for now markers are drastically restricted.